# Winforms with SQL Server : Define relations in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

When I write C# applications, I use to write sql relations as `inner join` for example, in the query:

```
select xxx from TableA as A inner join TableB...
```

I don't really see why I should define these realtions (hard defined) in Management Studio.

Should I, and why if required?

Regards

Comment: To enforce the integrity of your data. Doing some research on "data integrity" and more specifically "referential integrity" should give you an understanding of why defining relationships at the database design level is important.

Answer (score 0):

Two main reasons and a minor third one: data-integrity and performance - and documentation.

Performance is simple: if you define a relationship between two tables you will normally automatically create an index on those two columns, and your database will use those indexes to speed up look-ups when they can be used.

As for data-integrity, even though you leave the important part of your join out of your example, you assume in a join that a foreign key field can only contain values that exist in the primary key field. Your database can make sure of that, and will make sure of that when you define those relations in SQL server.
If you do not define those relationships, you could easily create a situation where you have, say, `Orders`, that belong to `Customer` 12345, who *does not exist* in your `Customer` table.
Or you could delete `Customer` 23456, leaving all their `Orders` in your system, but without an existing `Customer`.

A final reason is documentation: your database is not only made to be accessed by your code. If someone else accesses your database and sees only unconnected unrelated tables, how will they know that field `cstID` in table `CstOrderHdr` happens to be a reference to field `id` in table `Relations` where `Relation.RelTyp = 'Customer'`? Who is to stop them from filling in 0, null or a random number?

Comment: Thanks for your constructive answer,